# Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity vs HttpContext.User.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, form-authentication, current-principal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference between http.context.user and thread.currentprincipal and when to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057937/difference-between-http-context-user-and-thread-currentprincipal-and-when-to-use)

What's the difference between these two in an ASP.NET application?

I know the `HttpContext.User.Identity` is set when the user is authenticated through `FormsAuthentication`. But when is the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` set?

Do they always hold the same value?

Does that still hold true for other layers of the application that do not have access to a `HttpContext`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HttpContext.User.Identity is the current logged in user in your web app.

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal` applies only when the `<authentication mode = "windows"/>`. Normally this is using with Windows based applications (Winforms,WPF..)

Comment: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` still works with `mode="forms"`...

Comment: @Nico : But it doesn't give you the currently login user. It will give you the windows user details instead. So, in this case Thread.CurrentPrincipal doesn't make much sense.

Comment: In Forms Authentication the Thread.CurrentPrincipal can become unsynched from the HttpContext.User.Identity.  See this old blog from [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx).  Also see this newer [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16693746)

Answer (score -3):

if you use   the HttpContext.User.Identity equals the Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Comment: Not true. If you spin off a thread in the background, HttpContext.User may change whilst the thread is running, depending on how you are running it.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User will be the current logged in web-user.
Thread.CurrentPrincipal will be the principal for whomever is running the worker process (Thread).
In the case of a forms/wpf app it makes sense because the user you're running the application under is the one you're interested in.