# Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Id vs this.User.Identity.GetuserId()

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have found legacy code in API controllers.

```
var user = await _userService.FindAsync(x => x.UserName == Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
if (user == null) return NotFound();
```

I don't know when I should use `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` instead of simple `this.User.Identity.GetUserId()`.

What is difference?

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3057979/706456) is what you are after. One will be an account of OS system where the thread is running. The other one will be web user identity.