# ASP.NET User Identity

Tags: asp.net, identity

whats the difference between `Environment.UserName`; and `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`;  and `HttpContext.Current.User` ?

As per my understanding `HttpContext.Current.User` returns Logged in user , `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returns the identuty under which code is running. But What is the use of `Environment.UserName`; ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between HttpContext.Current.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843271/whats-the-difference-between-httpcontext-current-user-and-thread-currentprincip)

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.UserName` returns just the user name string of the logged into the Windows OS user - i.e. 'JohnDoe'

`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returns NetBIOS user name of the logged into the Windows OS user - i.e. 'Fabrikam\JohnDoe'

`HttpContext.Current.User` returns the user object of the logged into the website user, given the website is leveraging the membership system. To get the username string you need to navigate through the Identity property:

`string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`