# C# Environ username and IIS username not matching

Tags: c#, iis

I have created an Intranet application for storing customer related details. The application also stores Windows Logon nID of the person who submitted the form (`Envionment.Username`). Everything looks and works good in Localhost. The form got deployed in IIS and now `Environment.Uusername` returns a value from application pool inside IIS. We have set an identity value in IIS application pool which has access to the database and that value is getting returned for Environment.Username.

I tried with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` but it returns a empty value.

WindowsAuthentication and AnonymousAuthenication are set to ENABLED in IIS.

Any leads on this would be of great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, This should work if you are using windows authentication.

Comment: Have you tried disabling `Anonymous Authentication`? From what I remember, the authentication models work in a hierarchy with the simplest one first (Anonymous) and that will also work as there is nothing to gather/authenticate. Also, you *may* need to enable `Impersonation` to get the Logged On User credentials when accessing the database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843271/whats-the-difference-between-httpcontext-current-user-and-thread-currentprincip/1843367#1843367 You should never call the methods above, but use what ASP.NET framework offers on pages or controllers natively.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @JayV i tried to set Anonymous Authentication disabled, but i am getting HTTP ERROR 404.15 - NOT FOUND

Comment: Can anyone please tell me , why i am unable to run the application locally by setting Anonymous Authentication in disabled state?